Proving a set is open inequality confusion
I have the metric space $(\mathbb R, d)$ where $d = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$. I have found the open ball to be $B(r,a) = 
\begin{cases}\mathbb R &\text{ if } r \geq 1 \\ (a - \frac{r}{1-r}, a + \frac{r}{1-r}) &\text{ if } 0 <r < 1) \end{cases}$
I need to prove that the set $(0,1)$ is open, so for all $0<a<1$ there must exist $r>0$ such that $B(r,a)$ is a subset of $(0,1)$. So for $0<a<1$, if I consider $0<r<1$, I require $a - \frac{r}{1-r} \geq  0$ and $a + \frac{r}{1-r} \leq 1$, which gives $r \leq \frac{a}{a+1}$ and $r \leq \frac{1-a}{2-a}$
This means choosing $r$ such that $0 < r \leq \min(\frac{a}{a+1},\frac{1-a}{2-a}) < 1$ satisfies that $B(r,a)$ is a subset of $(0,1)$ for all $0<a<1$.
My only confusion is if I am able to choose the strict inequalities that I used, or if I have to replace them by $<$ and $>$ instead?
